# Email Regular Expression for a specific domain

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression for a particular domain using Javascript but am running into an issue that I can't quite understand.

I want to check if emails conform to

> (First Name)**.**(Last Name with numbers)@domain.com

I have this expression

```
r = new RegExp("\w*\.\w*@gmail.com")
```

but my results aren't what I expect

```
"foo.bar@gmail.com".match(r)
["r@gmail.com"]
```

Why am I missing the first part of the string?

Comment: Again: use literal `/\w*\.\w*@gmail\.com/`. Otherwise, it is the same as `/w*.w*@gmail.com/`. And it is matching `r@gmail.com`.

Comment: It's the shortest possible match isn't it? Why would it return another result?

Comment: I see that my escape characters are wrong. Thank you!